# Using Type-safe URLs with setMessage? (shamlet versus hamlet)

Tags: yesod, hamlet

How do I use a type-safe url with setMessage?

I want to change

```
 ...
 setMessage [shamlet|<span .warning>Warning! See Help.|]
 ...
```

to a message that contains a link.

From what I could gather thus far, it ought to work somehow like this

```
 ...
 renderer <- getUrlRender
 let html = [hamlet|<span .warning>Warning! See #
                     <a href=@{HelpR}> Help!|]
 setMessage $ toHtml $ html renderer
 ...
```

but that code just gives me confusing error messages all over the file.

I did read the printed Yesod Book Chapter on Shakespearian Templates, but I found that it is not very explicit on the involved types. For instance what type does `[hamlet|...|]|` produce? Without URL-Interpolation, ghci reports `t -> Markup` but with URL-Interpolation inside, I just get errors.

I am further confused by all the type synonyms involved, e.g. `[shamlet|...|]` delivers something of type `Html`, while `setMessage` expects a `Html ()`. I do not know how to look these up easily: Hoogle often finds nothing on the topic, while Google always finds possibly outdated versions (with examples that no longer work) - sure I get to the newest version eventually, but is there a place where I get an easy overview over these? (Can ghci list all synonyms for a type?)

Note that I actually want to produce the message in a purely functional code fragment, which is later on used by a handler. So that is why I would like to separate the URL rendering from where the hamlet is specified. Thanks for any pointer in the right direction!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want to use [getUrlRenderParams](http://haddocks.fpcomplete.com/fp/7.4.2/20130301-40/yesod-core/Yesod-Handler.html#v%3agetUrlRenderParams). Strangely enough, a related discussion came up on IRC today. Hamlet templates take a URL rendering function as their first argument, and that function must take two parameters: a type-safe URL, and a list of query string parameters. getUrlRender returns a function that doesn't take the query string parameters, which is why you need getUrlRenderParams instead.

Comment: Thank you! So at least I was close. I have struggled with the problem for quite a while, especially since I don't know much about web design and thought maybe it is bad style to use links together with setMessage, as the Yesod Book does not mention anything like it.

Well, that someone else asks on the same day is a strange coincidence indeed, but I never use IRC myself, and I am just tinkering on my own to learn more about Yesod. So maybe there ought to be an example somewhere.